# Subscribing or binding to an existing Intent service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, intentservice

I have an app that has an initial activty that list some files within a list view. When an item is clicked within the list it takes you to a detail activity of that specific file.

In the detail view I have a button called download, when you click on download it starts a IntentService which sets off the file to be downloaded as such:

```
downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AppDetailsActivity.this, AppDownloadService.class);
        intent.putExtra(Consts.APP_DOWNLOAD_RECEIVER_KEY, new DownloadReceiver(new Handler()));
        startService(intent);
    }
});
```

the DownloadReceiver class is used to update a progress bar within the the download file's detailed activity.

Now what I want to do...

If the user is currently downloading the file from the detail activity, and then goes back to the previous activity, I want the activity to somehow subscribe/bind to the same IntentService and retrieve the results so that it can show a progress bar within the list item of the file that is downloading.

1. Is this possible using an IntentService?
2. Is IntentService the right thing?
3. Are there any examples (as I have not found anything that show's me how to do this)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a download you sure can use an `IntentService`. It runs on a different thread. Also, keep in mind that calling `startService()` several times for that `IntentService` it will create a queue and will handle one intent at a time.

To show the progress on an `Activity` I don't belive broadcasts are the right thing. Although it is highly likely they are process in order, the framework or Android itself won't guarantee an order upon delivery. This means that you can get the broadcast for 50% and then the broadcast for 40%. For this I recommend that you take a look on this example: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample

It can look a little bit more complicated but you'll have a 2 way communication that you can rely on.

Comment: Thanks for this. I need to revisit this functionality again, so this might be an opportunity to improve things. So with an IntentService how would I ensure that my progress bar gets updated in the activity? Bear in mind that if the activity is closed and the relaunched (whilst the file is downloading still), the activty must retrieve the progress of the downloaded file so far to show on the progress bar. The example only shows handling of the activity start and end unless I am missing something? Thanks.

Comment: The example shows a communication between the activity and service. The activity can send a message asking for the progress and the service sends the progress within the response

Comment: Yep, thanks I have got it working now with the messages and incoming handler, and it works much better now. Thanks!

Comment: I'm also in similar situation. Can I know how you managed to communicate to the service when the activity is closed and relaunched?

Comment: @Sreekanth is right, this answer does not provide enough explanation of how (if possible) to bind to a running intentservice after launch.

Comment: Thank you for answer!
I see many examples of binding **Activity** and **Service**, but, will it work if I will bind the **Activity** with **IntentService**?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution. It turns out that I have to use a broadcast intent to publish the progress in my service; And use BroadcastReceiver in my activities to retrieve the results.

The link below shows an example of sending and retrieving results from services via broadcasts.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/